# F#: Array of n Empty Lists

Tags: arrays, f#

I want to create an Array which contains n empty lists, but the compiler has some problems with the type.

Both

```
Array.create 5 []
```

and

```
[| for i in 1..5 -> [] |]
```

does not work. Does anyone have any ideas what´s wrong with my code?

I expect the following output:

```
[| []; []; []; []; [] |]
```

The reason I want to create such an Array is that I in the next step want to create lists step by step in the Array by appending elements to the empty lists.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add type annotations or F# cannot say what type of list `[]` has.

For example, create an array of `int list` like so:

```ml
> Array.create<int list> 5 [] ;; 
val it : int list [] = [|[]; []; []; []; []|]
```

Or in a generic function:

```ml
> let foo<'t> n = Array.create<(int * 't) list> n ;; 

val foo : n:int -> ((int * 't) list -> (int * 't) list [])
```